How can we trigger third party password manager prompt to save credentials on Login in compose android?
I need to autofill my credentials on login page using default password manager or third party password manager which ever app user selects in settings. I want to achieve it for a compose screen.
Tried using below code but it did not work.
fun Modifier.autofill(
  autofillTypes: List<AutofillType>,
  onFill: ((String) -> Unit),
) = composed {
  val autofill = LocalAutofill.current
  val autofillNode = AutofillNode(onFill = onFill, autofillTypes = autofillTypes)
  LocalAutofillTree.current += autofillNode

  this.onGloballyPositioned {
    autofillNode.boundingBox = it.boundsInWindow()
  }.onFocusChanged { focusState ->
    autofill?.run {
      if (focusState.isFocused) {
        requestAutofillForNode(autofillNode)
      } else {
        cancelAutofillForNode(autofillNode)
      }
    }
  }
}

TextField(
    label = stringResource(R.string.email_address),
    text = email,
    errorMessage = loginState.emailError.orEmpty(),
    imeAction = ImeAction.Next,
    imeActionCallback = KeyboardActions(
        onNext = {
            viewModel.onEvent(LoginUiEvent.NextClicked)
            focusManager.moveFocus(FocusDirection.Down)
        }
    ),
   modifier = Modifier
        .connectNode(handler = autoFillHandler)
        .defaultFocusChangeAutoFill(handler = autoFillHandler)
)



What exactly do you mean by "it did not work"? Is the app crashing? Also, please edit your post and include the code showing how you used your autofill Modifier.

Nothing is happening with this code.....not getting any prompt to save credentials or to autofill credentials
